# How to create a list view with non-clickable header in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to create a header with the description using a list-view in xamarin forms.

I need to use the separate styles for header and details in the list view.

I'm trying with the following code,

```
<ListView RowHeight="74" ItemsSource="{Binding UserEmailList}" IsGroupingEnabled="true">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
          <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
          <Label Text="{Binding Heading}" Style="{StaticResource labelHeaderTitle}"/>
          <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Label Text="{Binding EmailAddress}" Style="{StaticResource labelListItem}">
              </Label>
              <Image HeightRequest="16" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="arrow.png" Margin="0,0,15,0"></Image>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

But, when i use the  tag, the list view always comes up empty.

Please let me know how to create this using XAML in xamarin forms.

[image]

```
public class EmailItemViewModel
{
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public bool HasEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileEmailAddressViewModel : ProfileDetailsViewModel
{
    public ProfileEmailAddressViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Email addresses";
        LoadUserEmailList();
    }

    private List<EmailItemViewModel> userEmailList;

    public List<EmailItemViewModel> UserEmailList {
        get { return userEmailList; }
        set
        {
            if(value != null)
            {
                userEmailList = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private void LoadUserEmailList()
    {
        UserEmailList = new List<EmailItemViewModel>();
        foreach (var package in Employee.Packages)
        {
            EmailItemViewModel emailItemViewModel = new EmailItemViewModel();
            emailItemViewModel.Heading = package.Employer.Name.ToUpper();
            emailItemViewModel.EmailAddress = package.WorkEmailAddress;
            emailItemViewModel.HasEmailAddress = HasEmailAddress(package.WorkEmailAddress);

            UserEmailList.Add(emailItemViewModel);
        }

        EmailItemViewModel personalEmail = new EmailItemViewModel();
        personalEmail.Heading = "PERSONAL EMAIL";
        personalEmail.EmailAddress = Employee.HomeEmailAddress;
        personalEmail.HasEmailAddress = HasEmailAddress(Employee.HomeEmailAddress);

        UserEmailList.Add(personalEmail);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrap the header in `StackLayout`, I'm surprised it didn't throw compilation error. Also for settings using [TableView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview) might be a better approach

Comment: Could you please elaborate, when u say "Wrap the header in StackLayout". Sorry, was not able to get you. Will tableview can i bind a list of objects in XAML?

Comment: Your HeaderTeamplate ViewCell has 3 Views in it, wrap them in a StackLayout. Also, post your ViewModel where the grouping is done. No, you can't bind list to a TableView. This looks like a settings page, which usually doesn't have more values, hence suggested TableView

Comment: @Shan Have updated my query with the view model details.

Comment: You are missing groups!! Just setting the `Heading` is not enough, you have to specifically group the ObservableCollection. Take a look at the [Static Grouping Sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/ListView/Grouping) or [Dynamic Grouping](https://montemagno.com/enhancing-xamarin-forms-listview-with-grouping/)

Answer (score 1):

```
        Try Listview.Header 
        like this 

    <ListView RowHeight="74" ItemsSource="{Binding UserEmailList}" IsGroupingEnabled="true">
        <ListView.Header>     
              <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>
              <Label Text="{Binding Heading}" Style="{StaticResource labelHeaderTitle}"/>
              <BoxView Style="{StaticResource separator}"></BoxView>

        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
<ViewCell.View>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Label Text="{Binding EmailAddress}" Style="{StaticResource labelListItem}">
                  </Label>
                  <Image HeightRequest="16" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="arrow.png" Margin="0,0,15,0"></Image>
                </StackLayout>
</ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
```

Comment: This displays only fully qualified property name as header not the value, but nothing in the description.  Also, all the headers are coming as one list and then empty details list.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but still the list is not coming as expected. I have created a sample xaml and code behind in the query, could you please let me know what could I be missing here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53066123/not-able-to-create-a-listview-with-headers-with-xamarin-forms